# How do I get the wacom zoom wheel working?

Tags: input-devices, wacom, graphics-tablet, bamboo

I'm trying to get the zoom wheel on my wacom bamboo to work. Though i have very little idea of how to do so. I tried using xinputwacom (i think) however it moaned it was missing something. Is there anyway of running wacom-tools on 10.04?

A bit more reading here on wacom-tools
http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/09/wacom-support-in-linux.html

Comment: Please edit your question topic so it's clearer to understand on the front page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how I can make it clearer. The title suggests its about the wacom zoom wheel. The description states my problem fairly clearly. I've installed the drivers and it all works not but xsetwacom doesn't work, it doesnt list any devices. I think my symlinks for everything are completely ruined.

Comment: I tried everything to get this on 10.04 and I couldn't (bad news). I am running 11.10 now and it works out of the box (good news).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're going to want to be looking into is a command called [xsetwacom](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/index.php/howto/xsetwacom)

I think this is included in default repositories in Ubuntu lucid/maverick.

AbsWUp and AbsWDn correspond to "up" and "down" scrolling on the touch-ring.

Your command is going to be something like:

`xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo pad" AbsWUp "key +"` 
(setting scroll-up to "+" key to zoom in.)

However, they've changed around the way commands are set a little bit in the newest release of xsetwacom. I'm not sure precisely how to phrase this command to get it to work in Ubuntu 10.04 +.

You can get help for this at the linuxwacom project mailing list: 
lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/linuxwacom-discuss

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like wacom-tools is supported under 10.04. Linux.com did just post a walkthrough of getting the wacom bamboo working with 10.04. [link text](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/347367-using-a-bamboo-tablet-with-ubuntu-1004)