# Cannot assign keys to Wacom scroll wheel anymore

Tags: xorg, wacom, graphics-tablet

my Wacom Graphire 4 used to work perfectly well until, I think, Ubuntu 10.4. At that point something changed in the configuration and I couldn't assign a key to the **scroll wheel** anymore (note: the pad's scroll wheel, not the mouse's), i.e this command:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Graphire4 6x8 pad" AbsWDn "key +"
```

returns silently without error but nothing happens. Same goes for `AbsWUp`, `RelWDn`, `RelWUp`.

Apparently though the problem is even deeper as pressing the wheel in a `xev` window doesn't seem to have any effect.

Moreover I am thoroughly confused on how the various pieces (kernel driver, xorg driver, evdev, HAL, xinput?) are supposed to work together and if the `wacom` module that ships with Ubuntu is the one from [linuxwacom](http://linuxwacom.sf.net) or not.

Any ideas? I don't want to become an X.org hacker just to understand what's going on... it used to work!

NOTE: I have already read [question 3940](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3940/wacom-zoom-wheel), but that's not the same problem.

Comment: Do you know what change the problem occurred after? Did you upgrade Wacom drivers, or upgrade to a new Ubuntu release? Are you still using Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: @Murat: to have Wacom working in 10.04 I had to change the configuration files, I think because HAL was dropped, but I'm not sure. Now I'm on 10.10 and the problem is still there. It used to work, and I'm pretty sure I had been using the drivers provided with the distribution before (it's been a while since I last recompiled the linuxwacom stuff).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the same issue with the Graphire, but there's been a bug in recent Linuxwacom releases that prevented assigning keys to the wheel on the Intuos4. I'll edit this answer once I find a link to the relevant bug; you might have to wait for a fix to it.

On Ubuntu 10.04, I used [Martin Owens' PPA](https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/wacom-plus/) for updated drivers, which made button assignment possible on the Intuos4, but didn't help with the wheel.

Comment: thanks for the link, it looks useful; I'm waiting eagerly for your edit :) By the way, assigning keys works ok for everything except the wheel in my case.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to find the bug report. It might be a good idea for you to ask for assistance on the linuxwacom-discuss mailing list.